# Buffered Kelvin-Varley divider in AD7849

Tags: dac

In ADI's [data sheet of AD7849](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7849.pdf), page 11, it gives the internal structure as below:

[image]

It uses a so called 'Buffered Kelvin-Varley Divider'. But i'm not very clear with it's explanation

> To prevent nonmonotonicity in the DAC due to amplifier offset
>   voltages, DAC1 and DAC2 leap-frog along the resistor string. For
>   example, when switching from Segment 1 to Segment 2, DAC1 switches
>   from the bottom of Segment 1 to the top of Segment 2 while DAC 2
>   remains connected to the top of Segment 1. The code driving DAC3 is
>   automatically complemented to compensate for the inversion of its
>   inputs. This means that any linearity effects due to amplifier offset
>   voltages remain unchanged when switching from one segment to the next,
>   and 16-bit monotonicity is ensured if DAC3 is monotonic.

How the 'leap-frog' connections for DAC1 and DAC2 can prevent nonmonotonicity caused by amplifier offset voltage?  Anyone can explain it in more details?

Answer (score 3):

Clever arrangement.

Consider what the interpolation DAC 3 is doing.

When interpolating the first s1-s2 segment, DACs 1/2 connect by S1 and S2, DAC3 'creeps' along from Vs1 to Vs2. When it finally reaches the Vs2 end-stop, the next segment s2-s3 is brought into use, S1 opens and S3 closes. At this point, **DAC3 (via S2 and A1) has the same voltage on it that it had for the first segment**. The amplifier used for that connection is still A1. Even if A1 has an input offset, when DAC 3 creeps along from Vs2 to Vs3, there is no break in the nice monotonic voltage steps at Vs2.

In a conventional buffered Kelvin Varley, A1 and A2 are switched without inverting the operation of DAC 3, A1 always goes to the 'top' of DAC 3, A2 to the 'bottom'. That means that the Vs2 tap will see the offset voltage of either A1 (when interpolating the s1-s2 segment) or A2 (when interpolating the s2-s3 segment). If there is a difference in the input offsets of A1 and A2, that will show up as a step in the output voltage. If that step is larger than the resolution of DAC3, then you will have non-monotonicity.

Comment: Thanks. " The code driving DAC3 is automatically complemented to compensate for the inversion of its inputs. " I'm not very clear with this word, yet. can you explain more ?

Comment: Which word? Code - in this context a sequence of 0s and 1s, that represent a binary number. Automatically - you don't have to alter the code you drive it with, it handles the inversion. Complemented - inverted. Compensate - undo the effect of.

Comment: "it handle the inversion", you mean there is a 'inversion' of the input code, though it's transparent for the user?